# Send multiple, specific sheets as PDF - Google Sheets

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, google-sheets-api

I am trying to send specific sheets as PDF email attachments.

I have the code below, which is able to export and send each specified sheet as separate emails, but I would like it to be able accept multiple, user specified sheet names and send them all as a single attachment in a single email. Multiple attachments in a single email are just as good.

The code I currently using:

```js
function mainSendEmail(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('SEND EMAIL', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES) {
    emailSpreadsheetAsPDF_CHARTS();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    emailSpreadsheetAsPDF_PL();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    emailSpreadsheetAsPDF_Wages();
} else {
  Logger.log('Do not send');
}
}

function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF_CHARTS() {
  const sheetToPrint = "CHARTS"; // name of the sheet to print
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // the sheets to use
  const email = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('CHARTS').getRange('I89').getValue().toString(); // grab the email address 
  const date = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('CHARTS').getRange('I91').getValue().toString(); // grab the date
  const subject = `SF - Flotta (${date})`; // the subject of the email
  const body = emailBody; // body of the email
  const shID = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToPrint).getSheetId(); // the ID of the sheet
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?'.replace('SS_ID', ss.getId()); // url of the spreadsheet
  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf'
    + '&format=pdf'// export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    + '&size=A4'// size of the PDF (legal / A4 / letter)
    + '&portrait=true'// orientation of the PDF (false for landscape)
    + '&sheetnames=false'
    + '&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
    + '&pagenumbers=false'
    + '&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
    + '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    + '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER'  //LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT
    + '&vertical_alignment=MIDDLE'       //TOP/MIDDLE/BOTTOM
    + '&scale=' + 4 // 1 = Normal 100% -- 2 = Fit to width -- 3 = Fit to height -- 4 = Fit to Page
    + '&gid='+shID; // the sheet's Id
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  // generate the PDF file
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  
  // send the email to the specified address with the specified body text and attached PDF file
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [{
            fileName: `SF - Flotta (${date})` + ".pdf",
            content: response.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    });
}

function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF_PL() {
  const sheetToPrint = "QPL"; // name of the sheet to print
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // the sheets to use
  const email = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('CHARTS').getRange('I89').getValue().toString(); // grab the email address 
  const date = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('CHARTS').getRange('I91').getValue().toString(); // grab the date
  const subject = `SF - Flotta PL (${date})`; // the subject of the email
  const body = emailBody; // body of the email
  const shID = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToPrint).getSheetId(); // the ID of the sheet
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?'.replace('SS_ID', ss.getId()); // url of the spreadsheet
  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf'
    + '&format=pdf'// export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    + '&size=A4'// size of the PDF (legal / A4 / letter)
    + '&portrait=true'// orientation of the PDF (false for landscape)
    + '&sheetnames=false'
    + '&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
    + '&pagenumbers=false'
    + '&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
    + '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    + '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER'  //LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT
    + '&vertical_alignment=MIDDLE'       //TOP/MIDDLE/BOTTOM
    + '&scale=' + 4 // 1 = Normal 100% -- 2 = Fit to width -- 3 = Fit to height -- 4 = Fit to Page
    + '&gid='+shID; // the sheet's Id
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  // generate the PDF file
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  
  // send the email to the specified address with the specified body text and attached PDF file
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [{
            fileName: `SF - Flotta PL (${date})` + ".pdf",
            content: response.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    });
}

function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF_Wages() {
  const sheetToPrint = "QWages"; // name of the sheet to print
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // the sheets to use
  const email = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('CHARTS').getRange('I89').getValue().toString(); // grab the email address 
  const date = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('CHARTS').getRange('I91').getValue().toString(); // grab the date
  const subject = `SF - Flotta Bérek (${date})`; // the subject of the email
  const body = emailBody; // body of the email
  const shID = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToPrint).getSheetId(); // the ID of the sheet
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?'.replace('SS_ID', ss.getId()); // url of the spreadsheet
  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf'
    + '&format=pdf'// export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    + '&size=A4'// size of the PDF (legal / A4 / letter)
    + '&portrait=false'// orientation of the PDF (false for landscape)
    + '&sheetnames=false'
    + '&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
    + '&pagenumbers=false'
    + '&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
    + '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    + '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER'  //LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT
    + '&vertical_alignment=MIDDLE'       //TOP/MIDDLE/BOTTOM
    + '&scale=' + 4 // 1 = Normal 100% -- 2 = Fit to width -- 3 = Fit to height -- 4 = Fit to Page
    + '&gid='+shID; // the sheet's Id
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  // generate the PDF file
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  
  // send the email to the specified address with the specified body text and attached PDF file
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [{
            fileName: `SF - Flotta Bérek (${date})` + ".pdf",
            content: response.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    });
}
```

I know there is a lot of superfluous code in there, but I am quite new to coding, so this is the best I could do. I would really appreciate any help that I can get with the above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, I managed to make it work like this:

```js
function mainSendEmail(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('SEND EMAIL', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES) {
  
  //Activate sheets
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('QPL').activate();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('QWAGES').activate();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  // Run main script to send email
  emailSpreadsheetsAsPDF();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  // Deactivate sheets
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('QPL').hideSheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('QWAGES').hideSheet();

} else {
  Logger.log('Do not send');
}
}

function emailSpreadsheetsAsPDF() {
  const sheetToPrint1 = "CHARTS"; // name of the sheet to print
  const sheetToPrint2 = "QPL"; // name of the sheet to print
  const sheetToPrint3 = "QWAGES"; // name of the sheet to print
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // the sheets to use

  const email = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('CHARTS').getRange('I89').getValue().toString(); // grab the email address 
  const date = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('CHARTS').getRange('I91').getValue().toString(); // grab the date
  const subject = `SF - Flotta (${date})`; // the subject of the email
  const body = emailBody; // body of the email
  
  const shID1 = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToPrint1).getSheetId(); // the ID of the sheet
  const shID2 = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToPrint2).getSheetId(); // the ID of the sheet
  const shID3 = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToPrint3).getSheetId(); // the ID of the sheet
  
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?'.replace('SS_ID', ss.getId()); // url of the spreadsheet
  
  const exportOptions1 =
    'exportFormat=pdf'
    + '&format=pdf'// export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    + '&size=A4'// size of the PDF (legal / A4 / letter)
    + '&portrait=true'// orientation of the PDF (false for landscape)
    + '&sheetnames=false'
    + '&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
    + '&pagenumbers=false'
    + '&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
    + '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    + '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER'  //LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT
    + '&vertical_alignment=MIDDLE'       //TOP/MIDDLE/BOTTOM
    + '&scale=' + 4 // 1 = Normal 100% -- 2 = Fit to width -- 3 = Fit to height -- 4 = Fit to Page
    + '&gid='+shID1; // the sheet's Id
  var params1 = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  // generate the PDF file
  var response1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions1, params1).getBlob();
  
  const exportOptions2 =
    'exportFormat=pdf'
    + '&format=pdf'// export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    + '&size=A4'// size of the PDF (legal / A4 / letter)
    + '&portrait=true'// orientation of the PDF (false for landscape)
    + '&sheetnames=false'
    + '&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
    + '&pagenumbers=false'
    + '&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
    + '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    + '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER'  //LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT
    + '&vertical_alignment=MIDDLE'       //TOP/MIDDLE/BOTTOM
    + '&scale=' + 4 // 1 = Normal 100% -- 2 = Fit to width -- 3 = Fit to height -- 4 = Fit to Page
    + '&gid='+shID2; // the sheet's Id
  var params2 = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};

  // generate the PDF file
  var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions2, params2).getBlob();
  
  const exportOptions3 =
    'exportFormat=pdf'
    + '&format=pdf'// export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    + '&size=A4'// size of the PDF (legal / A4 / letter)
    + '&portrait=false'// orientation of the PDF (false for landscape)
    + '&sheetnames=false'
    + '&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
    + '&pagenumbers=false'
    + '&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
    + '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    + '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER'  //LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT
    + '&vertical_alignment=MIDDLE'       //TOP/MIDDLE/BOTTOM
    + '&scale=' + 4 // 1 = Normal 100% -- 2 = Fit to width -- 3 = Fit to height -- 4 = Fit to Page
    + '&gid='+shID3; // the sheet's Id
  var params3 = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};

  // generate the PDF file
  var response3 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions3, params3).getBlob();
  

  // send the email to the specified address with the specified body text and attached PDF file
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, {} subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [{
            fileName: `SF - Flotta (${date})` + ".pdf",
            content: response1.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        },{
            fileName: `SF - PL (${date})` + ".pdf",
            content: response2.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        },{
            fileName: `SF - Bérek (${date})` + ".pdf",
            content: response3.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    });
}
```